# Python request and parse xml from url

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

I am trying to download some files from a data source through their API. I am stuck on parsing the string and can not figure out how to parse it. I believe it is xml formatted but all my usual techniques from xml.etree.ElementTree are failing me. I am trying to get this data into a DataFrame that should look some like a number of columns and rows indexed by dates. Think I just need fresh eyes on it.

Below is the link and code. The value of returnValue is just a string and has not parsed anything. When I use an ElementTree I just get errors and do not find any elements. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
import json
URI = 'http://statistics.mla.com.au/ReportApi/RunReport?ReportGuid=76dd55db-5015-4bab-a73a-59de30836bb9'
resp=requests.get(URI)
results = resp.content
json_string = results.decode('utf-8')
data_dict = json.loads(json_string)
returnValue = data_dict.get('ReturnValue')
```

Comment: *How* do you "use an ElementTree" and what errors do you get?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how the beginning of `returnValue` looks like, properly formatted (as code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URI = "http://statistics.mla.com.au/ReportApi/RunReport?ReportGuid=76dd55db-5015-4bab-a73a-59de30836bb9"
data = requests.get(URI).json()["ReturnValue"]

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select("[AttributeName4]"):
    month = row.find_previous(attrs={"CalendarMonth": True})
    year = row.find_previous(attrs={"CalendarYear2": True})
    all_data.append(
        (
            year["CalendarYear2"],
            month["CalendarMonth"],
            row["AttributeName4"],
            row["Textbox3"],
        )
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Year", "Month", "Country", "Amount"])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
   Year    Month      Country      Amount
0  2022  January        Total  43361.8952
1  2022  January           US   6757.7215
2  2022  January        Japan   10214.278
3  2022  January  South Korea   9288.1666
4  2022  January        China   8779.9538
```

Comment: That is perfect. Did not think to use BeautifulSoup.